# How to display serial numbers in foreach loop while querying posts?

Tags: custom-post-types

Ok, I have a custom post type to store list of urls. I would like to print those urls with serial numbers. I used foreach loop.

```
foreach($urls as $url){
echo $url;
```

I got n number of urls as output. But i want to print serial numbers in each url like 1,2,3 and so on.
I don't want to use unordered list. Because i want to style my serial numbers too. So is there any way to print serial numbers?

Comment: Do you need to guarantee the serial numbers are always the same for every URL, on every page load. Or is it just a serial number generated for that particular page load / query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
echo '<ul>';

$sn_count = 1;
foreach($urls as $url){
    echo '<li><span class="serial-number">'.$sn_count.'</span> '.$url .'</li>';
    $sn_count++;
}

echo '</ul>';
```

You can then style your serial numbers with the `serial-number` class.

Comment: +1 Hey bro, Thanks your code working perfectly. I think there is a little bug in your code. $sn_count = $sn_count + 1;

Comment: Has it occured to you that lists can be output with numbers? Switch that list to an ordered list and you'll essentially have the same thing(without the need to use a counter).

Comment: To me yes, but from what i understood he wants to style each number differently,    also i posted `$sn_count = $sn_count + 1;` to help him understand the incrementing process .

Comment: How to get 2 digit  like 01,02-------11,12---20